# bitbucket-build-status-notifier plugin for jenkins reports wrong status

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, bcbsn

Jenkins should notify bitbucket if a job that is linked to a branch has passed or falied, and it does:

[image]

But for some reason, in the branch view, it doesn't notify about the result of the last build, and says it failed even if the last build has passed:

[image]

How do I make it refer to the result of the last build only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today it was released a new version of the plugin for jenkins bitbucket-build-status-notifier which allows exactly what you need to avoid the problem you describe. It's new config option "Only show latest build status", just ensure this checkbox is checked and enjoy it.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hi I'm the maintainer of the bitbucket-build-status-notifier for Jenkins. Actually the plugin creates a new build status for every jenkins build execution for a given commit. That means that if you exec a build for a given commit id and it failed and later exec a new build for the same commir id and success, both status success and failed will remain in bitbucket, that's fine and not an issue. Anyways I understand your problem or desires and you are not the only one since there's already a [issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35083)
for solving it.

At the moment I've not much time for developing this new features but I'll do it as soon as possible.

Comment: Well..That's an answer too...Thanks!

Comment: I know this question is kind of old, but is there a way of doing the same in a pipeline build?